# Standardize $X,Y$ and Covariance Computes a Correlation, But...?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Well known correlation formula,

$$ Corr(X,Y) = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{SD(X)SD(Y)} 
$$

It can also be used as

$$
Corr(X,Y) = Cov \bigg( \frac{X-E(X)}{SD(X)}, \frac{Y-E(Y)}{SD(Y)}
\bigg) 
$$

That is after standardizing $X,Y$ the covariance computes the correlation. Algebraically however doesn't the above look like

$$ Cov(Z,Z) $$

where $Z \sim N(0,1)$? And in that case, what would the covariance be? Always 1 right? Which of course cannot be true.

I understand one can see the standardization above as producing "z-scores" for both $X$ and $Y$, then using these scores covariance is computed. Intuitively this makes sense, however algebraicaly the above move is something I could have done, and I wonder why one should not do this.

Comment: X and Y are not they same, are they?

Comment: No they are not. But standardizing produces the same $Z$ no?

Comment: And also there is no reason to think of a normal distribution (if that's what you mean with $N(0,1)$).

Comment: Standardizing gives the same *if* there is a linear relation like $X=aY+b$ with $a>0$.

Comment: Yes I meant normal dist with $N(0,1)$. Sure, I dont have to think that way, but take any random var, subtract the mean, divide by standard deviation, you get a random var distributed as standard normal. Which is $Z$. Then I end up with $Cov(Z,Z)$

Comment: No. You get a distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$. That's all. Not necessarily normal.

Comment: @drhab Ahaa.. Okay, that is interesting. Is this true? I.f.f. $X$ was normal itself then standardizing would get $Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments...................